# Given $n$ projection operators on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, show $V$ is the direct sum of the ranges of the projections.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations, direct-sum

I am using the textbook *Introduction to Vectors and Tensors* by Bowen and Wang to self-study linear and multilinear algebra. I was asked to prove one of the theorems left to the readers, but first I must explain a little bit of background:

A projection operator (more succinctly called a *projection*) on a vector space $V$ is an endomorphism $P: V \mapsto V$ with the property that $P^2(\vec{v}) = P(\vec{v}), \forall \vec{v} \in V.$
$R(P)$ and $K(P)$ denote the range and kernel of a projection $P,$ respectively. $I:V \mapsto V$ is the identity automorphism for $V.$

I want to prove the following, keeping in mind that we are only dealing with finite-dimensional vector spaces:
**Theorem:** If $P_k, k \in \{1, 2, .... , N\}$ are projections on $V$ with the following properties:
$(1)$ $P_k^2 = P_k$, $\forall k \in \{1, 2, ..., N\}$
$(2)$ $P_kP_q = \vec{0}$, $k \neq q$
$(3)$ $I = \sum_{k=1}^{N}P_k$

then $V = R(P_1)\bigoplus R(P_2)\bigoplus ... \bigoplus R(P_N)$, where $\bigoplus$ is the direct sum operation.

The proof consists of two parts: first, proving that
$(a)$ $V = \sum_{i=1}^{N}R(P_i)$, and then
$(b)$ proving that the direct sum is well-defined in this case.

My proof so far is as follows:

$(a)$ Suppose $\vec{v} \in V.$ Then by property $(3)$ and the definition of the identity automorphism, $\vec{v} = I(\vec{v}) = \sum_{k=1}^{N}P_k(\vec{v})$. It suffices to notice that each of the $P_k \in R(P_k)$ so every $\vec{v}$ can be decomposed into elements of the ranges of the projections as required.

$(b)$ I know a theorem that says that the direct sum of a finite number of subspaces $V_1 \bigoplus V_2 \bigoplus ...\bigoplus V_Q$ of $V$ must satisfy the following property:
$\forall R \in \{1, 2, ..., Q\},$ $V_R \cap \sum_{k=1}^{R-1}V_k +V_R \cap \sum_{k=R+1}^{Q} V_k = \{\vec{0}\}$.

Suppose $\vec{v} \in R(P_k) \cap \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}R(P_i) + R(P_k) \cap \sum_{i=k+1}^{N}R(P_i)$.

Then $\exists$ $\vec{v_1} \in R(P_k) \cap \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}R(P_i)$ and $\vec{v_2} \in R(P_k) \cap \sum_{i=k+1}^{N}R(P_i)$ such that $\vec{v} = \vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2}$ since the expression above is a sum of subspaces.

Since $\vec{v_1} \in \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}R(P_i)$, $\exists k-1$ vectors $\vec{u_1}, \vec{u_2}, ..., \vec{u_{k-1}}$ such that:

$\vec{v_1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}P_{i}(\vec{u_i})$.
By property $(3)$, $I(\vec{v_1}) = \vec{v_1} = \sum_{k=1}^{N}P_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}P_{i}(\vec{u_i})$
$=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}P_{k}(P_{i}(\vec{u_i}))$ by linearity.
By property $(2)$, this sums to $\vec{0}$, since $i \neq k$. So we have $\vec{v_1} = \vec{0}.$

By a similar argument, $\vec{v_2} = \vec{0}.$

Therefore, $\vec{v} = \vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2} = \vec{0}$, so the property $(b)$ is satisfied.

This concludes my proof. The only problem that I have with it is that I did not use property $(1)$ in my proof anywhere. Can somebody please tell me whether or not I am correct? And if I am wrong, can you please point out my fallacy?
Thank you so much for reading and helping.

Comment: A natural conjecture here is that $(1)$ should follow from $(2)$ and $(3)$, which might explain why you don’t need to explicitly invoke $(1)$. Can you verify this?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I've thought about that, but if that's true, then why is it even listed as part of the hypothesis? (1) follows from the fact that the $P_k$ are projections anyway, since that's the definition of a projection. Either my proof is wrong, or the wording of the theorem statement is bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

Conditions (2) and (3) do indeed imply (1), as noted in the comments. So the statement of the theorem is indeed awkward.

Suppose conditions (2) and (3) hold, and consider the case $N=2$, for simplicity.

Then $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$ and $I=P_1+P_2$. Multiply the second equation by $P_1$. What do you find?

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked something so obvious. Thank you for this answer. Other than that though, was my proof correct?

Comment: From what I see, no, unless I'm too tired: when you write $\vec{v_1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}P_{i}(\vec{u_i})$ and then multiply by $I$ and use property (3), you are wrong that everything gets annihilated. You've forgotten that you have chosen some *fixed* $k$. So your $v_1$ has the form $P_1u_1+\cdots + P_{k-1}u_{k-1}$. When you then multiply by $I$, not everything cancels, and this is where (1) comes in useful, even though it follows from (2) and (3).

Comment: However, the flaw is easy to repair: just note that $P_kv_1$ *does* vanish, so either $v_1=0$ or $v_1\notin R(P_k)$ (why? because if $v_1\in R(P_k)$ then $P_kv_1=v_1$ by property 1). The second possibility is ruled out by the hypothesis that $v_1\in R(P_k)$.

Comment: So the origin of my mistake was that I was simultaneously using k as both a bound variable and a free variable? I see. So if I change it to $I = \sum_{j=1}^{N}P_j$ then I should be able to avoid the mistake, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the mistake, and yes, you can avoid the mistake by choosing an unbound dummy index, but it's silly to multiply by $I$; just multiply by $P_k$, as I said in my last comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, sir. So I've made the following modification: we know that $\vec{v_1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{k-1}P_{i}(\vec{u_i})$, but we also know that $v_1 = P_{k}(\vec{u_k})$ for some $\vec{u_k}$ since $\vec{v_1} \in R(P_k))$. So applying $P_k$ gives $P_{k}(\vec{v_1})$ =$P_{k}(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}P_{i}(\vec{u_i}))$ = $\vec{0}$